# What does this line of code mean and how can I fix the error?

Tags: c#, excel

I have an error on this line of code and I couldn't step into it because the error pops right away. Could anyone please tell me what is this line of code trying to do exactly?

```
var image = ws2.Drawings.AddPicture(
    imagesLocations[i].Name, 
    Image.FromFile(imagesLocations[i].Tests
                                     .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsReference)
                                     .ImagePath));
```

**Error:**

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: C:\Users\.."full path"..\Initial.png

**Some declarations:**

```
ExcelWorksheet ws2 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Images");

// this is a list of locations, and "location" is a custom class                        
var imagesLocations = SelectedSession.GetTests()
    .Where(t => t.IsReference)
    .Select(t => t.Location)
    .OrderBy(t => t.DateCreated)
    .ThenBy(t => t.Name)
    .ToList();
```

`Test` is a custom object of a written class

`IsReference` is a local `Boolean` for `Test` under certain condition

`ImagePath` is a local string for `Test`

So the error is that it is trying to take an image from a path to put it in the excel file. However, the image doesn't exist. I need to understand that line of code so I can prevent it from happening. Any help of how can I do that is very helpful. Please and thanks

Comment: Create a variable for `imagesLocations[i].Tests.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsReference).ImagePath` to see what it evaluates to. According to the exception this returns `C:\Users\.."full path"..\Initial.png` which does not exist on your file-system. Also makes the code much easier to read.

Comment: `.Where(t => t.IsReference)` will only select those entries from your list that fit the condition, so you can simply omit this check when calling `FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsReference)` and use `FirstOrDefault()` instead which will simply select the very first item from your list or `null` if no such item exists.

Comment: @himBromBeere thanks for your comments. I broke it down as you said and indeed it is much easier to read and to maintain. I just spent too much time digging so my mind set blocked. I will post the answer if you may post any feedback. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @HimBromBeere suggested and he was right.

This is what I did that got me the error checking up and running:

```
var temp = imagesLocations[i].Tests.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsReference).ImagePath;
if (File.Exists(temp))
{
    var temp2 = Image.FromFile(temp);
    var image = ws2.Drawings.AddPicture(imagesLocations[i].Name, temp2);
    image.SetSize(375, 375);
    image.SetPosition(i, 0, 1, 0);
}
```